# Converting monthly data to quarterly in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I've created a time series running

`debit<-ts(t(data1[7,-1]),start=c(2006,1),freq=12)`

then, trying to convert freq=12 to freq=4 using aggregate()

```
debitq<-aggregate(debit,nfrequency=4)
```

I get the message

```
"Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument"
```

I've tried to include sum as FUN but doesn't work

ts:

```
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
2006  1151.20   1166.29   1176.28   1138.82   1151.16   1156.34   1154.89   1174.97   1201.12   1204.47   1225.78   1236.95 
2007  1228.42   1260.39   1278.27   1285.94   1299.29   1325.34   1289.39   1312.27   1315.92   1307.14   1329.95   1333.75 
2008  1311.34   1345.38   1356.27   1318.32   1337.18   1343.40   1297.92   1319.52   1335.10   1345.36   1374.38   1397.34 
2009  1352.24   1381.00   1398.24   1384.03   1388.31   1434.60   1457.09   1509.95   1488.93   1472.43   1491.84   1497.39 
2010  1457.66   1494.97   1495.12   1585.07   1614.42   1612.41   1601.38   1618.11   1626.17   1644.93   1666.35   1694.04 
2011  1628.99   1671.78   1695.05   1734.68   1746.29   1805.43   1734.45   1768.39   1808.74   1806.56   1833.54   1866.35 
2012  1801.11   1836.04   1855.93   1880.44   1922.03   1970.70   1876.81   1867.30   1904.96   1943.84   1965.22   2007.98 
2013  1925.81   1951.58   1940.53   1940.31   1935.20   1985.58   1957.00   1991.67   1988.86   2022.52   2069.44   2122.81 
2014  2046.30   2067.28   2080.61   2052.56   2122.92   2202.97   2173.18   2169.54   2183.60   2155.37   2208.96   2295.90 
2015  2247.88   2329.62   2441.20   2451.47   2496.23   2583.69   2603.96   2686.29   2734.63   2646.48   2716.92   2793.01 
2016  2749.88   2819.47   2886.70   2799.79   2878.87   2958.64   2956.51   2955.19   3046.91   3032.89   3092.66   3112.94 
2017  3053.35   3134.67   3234.14   3244.51   3253.03   3357.65   3341.38   3404.00   3430.83   3438.48   3493.38   3559.27 
2018  3528.31   3582.15   3636.33   3658.51   3716.71   3754.10   3748.84   3785.66   3779.48   3763.04   3826.74   3877.06 
2019  3808.26   3873.53   3917.95   3878.69   3890.85   3977.99
```

dput():

```
    V163 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 14L, 
    1L, 4L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 1L, 20L, 13L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    11L, 10L, 8L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 18L, 
    22L, 21L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", " 0,00 ", " 1,32 ", 
    " 1.497,49 ", " 1.826,87 ", " 10,06 ", " 10,80 ", " 122,91 ", 
    " 13,59 ", " 138,09 ", " 151,68 ", " 3,53 ", " 3,96 ", " 3.826,31 ", 
    " 3.977,99 ", " 309,25 ", " 36,67 ", " 399,70 ", " 4,38 ", 
    " 410,42 ", " 455,16 ", " 662,76 ", " 84,00 ", " 843,91 ", 
    " 948,54 ", "($)", "Jun/19"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L))
```

traceback():

```
> traceback()
2: apply(array(c(x[1:nend, ]), dim = c(len, nend/len, ncol(x))), 
       MARGIN = c(2L, 3L), FUN = FUN, ...)
1: aggregate.ts(debit, nfrequency = 4)
```

sapply(debit,class):

```
> sapply(debit, class)
   7 
"ts"
```

Comment: Can you add your data, please?

Comment: It needs to be displayed in a reproducible format.  Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and show the output of `dput(data)` where `data` is your data.  It's likely that you have character data which appears to be numeric but we can't really tell from the way it was displayed in the question.

Comment: @Berto 1. What does it say when you write write ```sapply(debit, class)```. 2.Run the code and type ```traceback()``` write after you get the error message. Add the ouput the traceback to the text of your question.

Comment: @Berto I copy-pasted your ```dput``` and it didn't work. Are you sure you haven't modified anything and this is your full ```dput```. Wrt the ```sapply(debit, class)```: my bad it should have been ```sapply(data, class)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see my best guess is that you load the data using `read.csv` or `read.table` from `utils`. Instead of NA  the original file that you were loading into R contained the empty string "" (the first level of the factor in the `dput`), which caused the entire column to be seen as character and turned to factors upon loading.
In this case you should do someting like this:

```
data <- read.csv(<YOURFILE>, <YOURARGUMENTS>, colClasses = "character",
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # or read.table(... whichever you are using
data[[1]] <- factor(data[[1]])
for(i in 2:ncol(data)) data[[i]] <- as.numeric(data[[i]])
```

Comment: I solved using "obj<-ts(as.numeric(data), start, freq)" instead. So the frequency change worked.